# AWS Route53 Linking Existing URL and Parse Server URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, mailgun, amazon-route53

I have a Parse server using mailgun to send email verification and reset password emails. To add this feature I need a `publicServerURL`. This is the link attached to the email body to confirm a user's email or reset their password. As of now, I am using my `serverURL` for the `publicServerURL` (not smart because allows potential access to my server information).

After a lot of digging through forums and discussions, I have found out  my parse server needs to be reachable at my Project's website (`project.com` made with Wix) domain with a full path so it can be something like https://project.com/parse. Supposedly this is suppose to be done through AWS Route53 by pointing a subdomain to my "Elastic Load Balancer that is serving my content", **but I have no idea how to do this.**

I have never used AWS Route53 and the forums are not helping. Can anyone please help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like what you're after is different than the forum post. A subdomain would be something like https://parse.project.com. https://project.com/parse would need path-based routing. Is Route 53 your domain's current registrar?

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Route53 is not my domain's current registrar, I received my domain through google clients and they transferred to Network Solutions so it can be pointed at my Wix website.

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to use Route 53 in this situation, since your domain is not assigned to their registrar, you will not be able to make any entries on it and you can't enter paths. Where is your Parse server located?

Comment: My Parse Server is with AWS EC2. Is there a way to link the `serverURL` with to my project.com domain? I fine with Route53 alternatives.

Comment: i am not familiar with Network Solutions, but you should be able to create an A Record for something like "parse.project.com" and point it at the public IP of your EC2. In your EC2's security group, you can limit traffic to only the IP and port of your serverURL

Comment: I am new to all of this and not sure where / how to start with that. Can you please help me on how to do this?